# What blending mode is this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, blending, blend-modes

I'm trying to reverse engineer a blending mode I've seen [on a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJS8R.png):

[image]

This was created by someone else using *Adobe's Scene7*. Unfortunately, I don't have access to this tool and I also was unable to reproduce it with other softwares.

I just would like to know the type of blending used so I can research its equation. I'm not interested in the warping effect caused by the overlay.

If you look at the top left corner of where the images overlap, you can see just a little bit of the background leaking to the foreground image.

The original images have the same dimensions and can be found below:

[image]
[image]

Any idea on how to duplicate this effect?

Comment: The original images can be found [here](https://imgur.com/INdUcxB) and [here](https://imgur.com/haoeZtC).

Comment: This is a fairly straight-forward task for PhotoShop. What have you tried?

Comment: @13ruce If you roll down the page you'll see I've already answered this question. Thanks for stopping by, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I originally stated in the question, I am not interested in the warping effect (aka. *distortion*). I already knew what they were because I've [implemented the algorithm for that effect years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20673435/176769).

To answer my own question, to reproduce the blending effect for that image:

- Apply a **Multiply** blend;
- Uses this result as the background for a **Hue** blend;

The resulting image will be the same as the one shared on the question. Also, the exact equations for these operations are defined on [*Compositing and Blending Level 1 (W3C)*](https://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1/#blendinghue).

For testing purposes, [here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f0akv7yq/9/) that loads the result of a *multiply* blend as the background and then executes a *luminosity* blend. Yes, I said *luminosity* instead of *hue* because either the implementation of **CSS blend modes** *hue* and *luminosity* are switched, or the equations and sample images from **W3C** are.

Answer (score 1):

It is **not** simply a blending mode.

**Displacement Maps** in Photoshop offer this ability.

http://www.psd-dude.com/tutorials/resources/displacement-map-filter-photoshop-tutorials.aspx

https://creativemarket.com/blog/giftorial-how-to-use-displacement-maps-in-photoshop

https://photoshopcafe.com/tutorials/dispmap/dispmap.htm

A simple Google search for *"Photoshop, warp photo on t-shirt"* turns up dozens of tutorials:

https://creativepro.com/add-realistic-artwork-wrinkled-surface-photoshops-displacement-map/

Comment: I am aware of displacement maps and how they work internally. A displacement map filter uses an overlay algorithm to copy the foreground over the background with some transparency rule. That's the part I'm interested in.

Comment: You mean the simple Multiply bending of the dark areas?

Comment: @karlphillip actually displacement does no such thing

Comment: @joojaa Correct! But I didn't mean it literally, my apologies! When the *displacement map filter* applies the distortion on the target image using the *map*, the distorted target image is then copied over the background through a blending technique. So my question is really about the blending process! My C++ implementation of the *displacement map filter* is [available here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9260717/176769). Unfortunately, it looks like I'm not going to find such level of mastery over blending modes from the Graphic Design SE site. It was a long shot anyway. Thank you both of you!

Comment: yeah we be artists.. not C++ developers :)

Comment: @karlphillip maybe in your case but there is no inherent need to blend with displacement. So its a totally spearate action. So no displacement algorithm does NOT use blending to do anyhing. Overlaying does. Even if you were to ask this on CG.SE you wouldnt get a very good answer as the image you provide is horrible. If i were to guess based crappy data id say its a desaturated then multiplied and normalized. But might also just be overlay and a alpha blend with some transparcy added. Garbage in garbage out you know But yes Scott lead you to somewhere else.

Comment: @karlphillip hav you tried plotting the response curve?

Comment: @joojaa I haven't. In case you have, can you share it? The funny thing of it all is that I never pointed you guys to Displacement Map Filters. In fact, I wanted everyone to stay away from that and just focus on the blend mode. **:'D**

Comment: @karlphillip i dont have time to. But since it is jpeg compressed so the results are all over the place anyway i was hoping yoid have better fidelity originals.